# Additional instances (IF OR AND)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am struggling to write a two-part formula in Column D of this sheet
[AND/IF/OR Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XxfcHGlRHHZ2-jejtom5RGbv23Mj6-zQvEb_kbyyKBs/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Q52607793 example]

The requirement is to look for "test1 or "test2" in Column A, if either are found, show `0` in column D.

If they are not then apply Part 2 which looks for the value in column B, if the number is greater than `1`, then subtract 1 from the entry and thus showing the additional instances based on the text in column A.

Realising my description may not be the best .. J. I have tried again below:

Alternatively, if you have a more efficient method, it would be greatly appreciated.

Part1

```
    Criteria 
A2 = test1 or test2

Value if True
0

Value if False
Part 2
```

Part 2

```
    Criteria 
B2 is greater than 1

Value if True
B2-1*C2

Value if False
0

=IF(B2>1,B2-1*C2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not crystal clear to me, but you seem to have done almost all the work, assuming you want something like, in D3 and copied down to suit:

```
 =IF(or(A3="test1",A3="test2"),0,if(B3>1,B3-C3,0))
```

A slightly simpler form:

```
=if(and(B3>1,A3<>"test1",A3<>"test2"),B3-C3,0)
```